# Update TextBlock in real time while typing in TextBox using Unity Prism in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I'm trying to update a TextBlock while typing in a TextBox using Prism Unity in WPF, But it only fires when I close the main window not while typing.

## ViewModel

```
private string _textName = "text";

public string TextName
{
    get { return _textName; }
    set
    {
        _textName = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(TextName));
    }
}
```

## View

```
<StackPanel>
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding TextName}" FontSize="30"></TextBlock>
     <TextBox Text="{Binding TextName}"></TextBox>
</StackPanel>
```

How do I get the TextBlock update in real time while typing in the TextBox without implementing a event_handler ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, property changed only fires when focus changes.

To fire as you type, change:

```
 <TextBox Text="{Binding TextName}">
 </TextBox>
```

...to:

```
 <TextBox Text="{Binding TextName, 
                 UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
 </TextBox>
```